# Python Process blocking the rest of application

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

i have a program that basically does 2 things:

opens a websocket and remains on listening for messages and starting a video streaming in a forever loop.

I was trying to use multiprocess to manage both things but one piece stops the other from running.

The app is

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(start_client())


async def start_client():
        async with WSClient() as client:
            
            pass

class WSClient:
    async def __aenter__(self):
        
        async with websockets.connect(url,max_size= None) as websocket:
            self.websocket = websocket
            await self.on_open() ## it goes
            p = Process(target = init(self)) # This is the streaming method  
            p.start()

            async for message in websocket:
                await on_message(message, websocket) ## listen for websocket messages
            
         
        return self
```

the init method is

```
def init(ws):
    logging.info('Firmware Version: ' + getVersion())
    
    startStreaming(ws)
    return
```

basically startStreaming has an infinite loop in it.

In this configuration, the stream starts but the on_message of the websocket it's not called because the Process function freezes the rest of the application.

How can I run both methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're telling [`multiprocessing.Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) to take the function returned by `init` and call it in a new process. What you want is for the process to call `init` itself (with an argument). Here's how you can do that:

```py
p = Process(target=init, args=(self,))
```

I have to note that you're passing an asynchronous websocket object to your `init` function. This will likely break as asyncio stuff aren't usually meant to be used in two threads, let alone two processes. Unless you're somehow recreating the websocket object in the new process and making a new loop there too, what you're actually looking for is how to [create an asyncio task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks).

Assuming `startStreaming` is already an async function, you should change the `init` function to this:

```py
async def init(ws):  # note the async
    logging.info('Firmware Version: ' + getVersion())
    await startStreaming(ws)  # note the await
    return
```

and change the line creating and starting the process to this:

```py
asyncio.create_task(init(self))
```

This will run your `startStreaming` function in a new task while you also read incoming messages at (basically) the same time.

Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the async context manager as everything could be just in a normal async function. If you're interested in using one for learning purposes, I'd suggest you to check out [`contextlib.asynccontextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.asynccontextmanager) and have your message reading code inside the async with statement in `start_client` rather than inside `__aenter__`.

Comment: thanks a lot, i found another solution using Threads but yours seems clearer because in this way i will have 2 asynchronous task running together. I need to pass the ws object to the init function because i need to send thought it in the startStreaming method.